# cyclicBarrier on calculate prime numbers

Tags: java, multithreading

i have to calculate the number of the prime numbers presents from `1` to `10000` , i divided the range into `8` threads (`numbers of my CPU cores`) so each thread has to check `1250` numbers. I don't understand  why at the end of the program i' m getting this as output:

```
numbers found: 0
```

workerThread:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class WorkerThread extends Thread {

    private CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;
    private PrimeNumber primeNumber;
    private int min;
    private int max;

    public WorkerThread(CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier, int min, int max,
            PrimeNumber primeNumber) {
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
        this.primeNumber = primeNumber;
        this.max = max;
        this.min = min;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        primeNumber.calculatePrimeNumber(min,max);

        try {
            cyclicBarrier.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        primeNumber.printNumbers();
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class PrimeNumber {

    private Integer totalPrimeNumber;

    private int min;
    private int max;
    private int limit;

    public PrimeNumber(int min, int max) {
        totalPrimeNumber = new Integer(0);
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public void calculatePrimeNumber(int min, int max) {

        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            for (int j = 3; j <= Math.sqrt(min); j++) {
                if (min % 2 == 0)
                    break;
                else if (min % j == 0) {
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
                found = true;
            }
            if (found) {
                totalPrimeNumber++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void printNumbers() {
        synchronized (totalPrimeNumber) {
            System.out.println("numbers found" + totalPrimeNumber);
        }

    }

    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    private void setLimit(int max) {
        this.limit = max;
    }

    private int getLimit() {
        return limit;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

        CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(cores);
        PrimeNumber primeNumber = new PrimeNumber(1, 10000);

        int numberToCheck = primeNumber.getMax() - primeNumber.getMin();
        int numberToDivide = numberToCheck / cores;

        primeNumber.setMin(1);
        primeNumber.setLimit(primeNumber.getMax());
        primeNumber.setMax(numberToDivide);

        for (int i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
            if (i == 7) {
                primeNumber.setMax(primeNumber.getLimit());
                WorkerThread workerThread = new WorkerThread(cyclicBarrier,
                        primeNumber.getMin(), primeNumber.getMax(), primeNumber);
                workerThread.start();
            } else {
                WorkerThread workerThread = new WorkerThread(cyclicBarrier,
                        primeNumber.getMin(), primeNumber.getMax(), primeNumber);
                workerThread.start();
                primeNumber.setMin(primeNumber.getMax() + 1);
                primeNumber.setMax(primeNumber.getMax() + numberToDivide);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only ever test the `min` value

```
for (int j = 3; j <= Math.sqrt(min); j++) {
    if (min % 2 == 0) // min never changes
        break;
    else if (min % j == 0)
```

Most likely you intended to test `i` in each case where you use `min`

This is where using a debugger or writing unit tests would have solved this problem for you.

I assume the purpose is to see lots of CPU being used.  If you wanted speed, you could optimise this a lot though I suspect the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) in one thread will be much faster.

Comment: May i ask you a clarification on `calculatePrimeNumber` ? i' ve a doubt on here, if each trhreads concurrently enter here can they interfere each other? i think no, because the variables are all locally.

Comment: @user582040 You are right, they can't interfere as each method is passed a copy which is local to that thread.

Comment: @user582040 If you wanted some hints on how to make it faster, you can think about how often you want to call `Math.sqrt(i)` as this is expensive, also you don't need to test `if (i % 2 == 0)` more than once for each `i`.